# Preposition after conclude

Tags: prepositions

If the police conclude that the person died by accident, should I say 'The police concluded in an accident' ?

To me, this sounds like they finish the story by having an accident.

Comment: Yes it does sound as though the police have an accident.

Comment: The police concluded that the death was due to an accident.  Or they concluded that it was an accidental death.

Comment: Note that this sense of "conclude" is synonymous with "determine" -- "The police determined that the death was due to an accident".  There is a somewhat different sense of the word, eg:  "The trial concluded in a hung jury."  This second sense is not synonymous with "determine".

Comment: Though 'finish in' and 'end in', meaning 'finish with the result of',  are sometimes used (It finished/ended in a three-way tie for second ...), 'conclude in' is unidiomatic in my opinion. And the usage you want is certainly unacceptable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - The sense of "conclude" here is not "finish" but "determine".  We're talking about *conclusions* (*determinations*) such as Sherlock Holmes might arrive at.  I suspect that this difference is a part of the OP's confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to look up the usage in *BBI Collocation* and I find nothing.  But I guess you would like some sentences like

> The concert concluded with a rousing chorus.

Therefore you can try

*The crime investigation concluded with an identified accident.*

However, if you want to place *police* on the subject slot, according the meaning and usage listed in AHD, I think you must use the *conclude* as a transitive verb, which should be 
*The police concluded the investigation with an identified accident.*

Comment: While it may be technically correct, using "concluded" twice in a single sentence is very poor form.  (And note that "conclude" has at least two distinct senses, so you can't simply take a usage from some example and apply it in an unrelated context without some appreciation of the difference.)

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. It should be only one *conclude*.

Comment: I ended up using something like this. I guess it just isn't possible to do with a preposition. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Conclude in" sounds wrong
You maybe try to translate the french verb "conclure à", which means : "to arrive at a conclusion"

However I'm not sure at all that "conclude at" would be correct.
I only know "conclude something", "conclude by ...", "conclude that ..."
As I'm not native speaker, wait another response

Comment: "Concluded at an accident" would suggest that the police stopped playing license plate bingo when they encountered an accident.

Comment: That's exactly the verb I'm trying to translate ;) I agree with Hot Licks